# How to detect server disconnection in javascript in shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have shiny app and I'm having unload event that display message when user don't save data, but it also shown when R is not running anymore (closed or crashed). Is there a way to detect if shiny app is not connected to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found in in [js events doc](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html), so my code look like this:

```js
var connected = false;
$(document).on('shiny:disconnected', function(event) {
   connected = false;
}).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
   connected = true;
});

$(window).unload(function() {
   if (connected) {
      return "Are you sure?";
   }
});
```